# Visual Studio Online VSO): Can't set environment variables from a build task

Tags: azure-devops

I've been banging my head trying to update a Build Task Variable across Tasks, running on a Hosted Agent within Visual Studio Online.

As per:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md

At the end of the first PS script I try to persist the variables in the env, for subsequent tasks to benefit from it:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST;]$resourceNameTemplate"
Write-Host "Result: $env:TEST"
Write-Host "Result: $env:test"
```

The output shows that it was never set.

```
2018-02-05T00:57:45.7295714Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable 
variable=TEST;]MYORG-MYAPP-MYBT-{RESOURCETYPE}
2018-02-05T00:57:45.7302525Z Result: 
2018-02-05T00:57:45.7309594Z Result:
```

Any help, much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the wrong expectation, only subsequent tasks can access the variable. [The documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md) describes it clearly:

> Sets a variable in the variable service of taskcontext. The first task can set a variable, and following tasks are able to use the variable. **The variable is exposed to *the following tasks* as an environment variable.**

If you split...

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=TEST;]$resourceNameTemplate"
Write-Host "Result: $env:TEST"
Write-Host "Result: $env:test"
```

...across two tasks then you should see `TEST` has been set as an environment variable.

Comment: Hum. Tried this across two tasks...not getting the expected results.

First task:
2018-02-05T23:55:44.3476123Z ##[debug]Processed: ##vso[task.setvariable variable=custom_task_vars_resourceNameTemplate;]MYORG-MYAPP-MYBT-{RESOURCETYPE}

Second task, reads it:

write-host "custom.task.vars.resourceNameTemplate: $(custom.task.vars.resourceNameTemplate)"

But result is:

2018-02-05T23:55:44.9490223Z Check that Variables have been updated:

2018-02-05T23:55:44.9515265Z custom.task.vars.resourceNameTemplate: MYORG-MYAPP-{ENVID}-{BRANCHNAME}-{RESOURCETYPE}

(sorry for the text munging)

Comment: Is it possible its a feature that is not available on VSO Hosted Agents running Build Tasks? Or that it won't update the field if it originally had a value (eg: Set at Queue time?)

Comment: Ah. Man. Got it... I was using a var name that had dots in it (custom.task.vars.foo). Which meant I was accessing it in my ps script using dashes ('custom_task_vars_foo'). You have to set it ...with dots (dashes end up in a new variable!) Duh. Thx!

Comment: Glad you got it working. VSTS is an extremely capable and polished product but the edit-build-test cycle of build plans is PAINFUL.